# How to save and load safetensors files when fine-tuning a model for sequence classification with transformers?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, safe-tensors

I am fine-tuning an AutoModelForSequenceClassification from the transformers library to classify free text into the five traits of personality. I am using different learning rates, attention and hidden dropouts, and I want to save the model with the best results.

The problem is that when I run this code on other computers, it works perfectly, and it saves all the files, including the safetensors files, in the output directory. However, when I run this code on my laptop, it saves all the files except for the safetensors files, which are missing. This prevents me from loading the model later and doing more experiments with it.

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this problem, and how to fix it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you compared the transformer versions? Is safetensors installed?